# list comprehension to combine 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have two sequence as below

```
t = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
alpha = ['a','b','c']
```

How to use list comprehension to modify t as below:-

```
t = [[1,2,3,'a'],[4,5,6,'b'],[7,8,9,'c']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the indices:

```
t = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
alpha = ['a','b','c']
print([t[i] + [alpha[i]] for i in range(len(alpha))])
```

Answer (score 5):

use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
t = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
alpha = ['a','b','c']
new_list = [a+[b] for a, b in zip(t, alpha)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'a'], [4, 5, 6, 'b'], [7, 8, 9, 'c']]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `zip` to get corresponding pairs of elements, and from there it's just a matter of joining:

```
>>> t = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> alpha = ['a','b','c']
>>> [x[0] + [x[1]] for x in zip(t,alpha)]
[[1, 2, 3, 'a'], [4, 5, 6, 'b'], [7, 8, 9, 'c']]
```

Comment: This appears to be the most pythonic way to do it. This is a clear list comprehension that can be used in other situations that require two lists to be iterated over and manipulated in some way.